# ERROR 404 for js and css files, Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, directory

I get error 404 when trying to get the path of my css and js files. Any help will be appreciated, I'm using Laravel 5.8

```
<link href="{{asset('./public/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{asset('./public/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('./public/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js')}}"></script>
```

**Here's my directory**

[image]

**Question 2: How can I access the files from node_modules? I also get error 404**

This is my code for accessing node_modules files:

```
<link href="{{asset('dist/css/datepicker.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="{{asset('dist/js/datepicker.min.js')}}"></script>

<!-- Include English language -->
<script src="{{asset('dist/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js')}}"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Try using this..... href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.js')}}"></script>
```

this the right answer...
:D

Comment: you cant access node modules. you need to compile. here's the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the './' and just do

```
<link href="{{asset('public/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and replace

```
<link href="{{asset('./public/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The asset will get the path of the public folder.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

**For CSS:**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Make your directory structure is like this for CSS: `/public/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css`

---

**For Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
```

Make your directory structure is like this for JS:

```
/public/js/jquery.js
/public/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
```